# Measurability wrt. product sigma-algebra

Tags: probability, measure-theory

My probability theory book (Kallenberg, Foundations of modern probability p 64 middle), it is implied that  if we have two seperable metric spaces $S_1$ and $S_2$ then if a random variable $X : \Omega \to S_1 \times S_2$ is measurable wrt. $\mathcal{B}(S_1) \times \mathcal{B}(S_2)$ then it can be written as $X = (Z_1,Z_2)$ where each $Z_i:\Omega \to S_i$ is measurable wrt. $\mathcal{B}(S_i)$.

I do not quite understand this. If, for example, in a simple case where X is an indicator variable $X(\omega) = s_1 1_A(\omega) + s_2 1_{A^c}(\omega)$ where $A \in \mathcal{B}(S_1) \times \mathcal{B}(S_2)$ and $s_i \in S_1 \times S_2$ then I do not see how we can write X as $X = (Z_1,Z_2)$ where each $Z_i:\Omega \to S_i$ is measurable wrt. $\mathcal{B}(S_i)$, since the set $A$ may not be on the form $A = B_1 \times B_2$ where $B_i \in \mathcal{B}(S_i)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can write $X=(Z_1, Z_2)$ for some $Z_i:\Omega\to S_i$. For example, $Z_1(\omega)$ is defined as the first coordinate of the vector $X(\omega)\in S_1\times S_2$. Now, denote the sigma algebra on $\Omega$ by $\mathcal{F}$. For any Borel set $A\in\mathcal{B}(S_1)$ we have:

$\{Z_1\in A\}=\{Z_1\in A, Z_2\in S_2\}=\{(Z_1,Z_2)\in A\times S_2\}\in\mathcal{F}$

So $Z_1$ is indeed measurable with respect to $\mathcal{B}(S_1)$. Similarly for $Z_2$.